# Function is rewriting variable. How is this possible?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

This function seems to be rewriting the value for the 'pages' variable and I'm at my wit's end on this one.

I've tried returning the variable through a function, hardcoding the variable into the function, and a pile of other things, but this seems like it should work.

**Any ideas?**

EDIT:

The output from  should be an array of objects formatted like this `{default: "Tax Return", safe: "taxreturn"}`. The function, when first called with `getPages('Both', 'overview', null)` and `getPages('Both', null, 'overview')` does this, but if you call it more times it will error and you will find that the 'pages' variable is now an array of objects.

```
var pages = [
    "Dashboard",
    "Overview",
    "Contacts",
    "Records",
    "Cash Flow",
    "Transactions",
    "Income",
    "Expenses",
    "Tax Return"
];

var getPages = function(format, includeOne, excludeOne)
{
    var pageStrings = pages;

    if(includeOne)
        for(var p = 0; p < pageStrings.length; p++)
            if(uriSafe(pageStrings[p]) == uriSafe(includeOne))
                pageStrings = [pageStrings[p]];

    if(excludeOne)
        for(var c = 0; c < pageStrings.length; c++)
            if(uriSafe(pageStrings[c]) == uriSafe(excludeOne))
                pageStrings.splice(c, 1);

    var outputArray = [];

    switch(format)
    {
        case 'UriSafe':
            for(var i = 0; i < pageStrings.length; i++)
                pageStrings[i] = uriSafe(pageStrings[i]);
            break;
        case 'Both':
            for(var x = 0; x < pageStrings.length; x++)
            {
                pageStrings[x] = {
                    default: pageStrings[x],
                    safe: uriSafe(pageStrings[x])
                };
            }
            break;
        default:
    }

    function uriSafe(str)
    {
        return str.replace(' ', '').toLowerCase();
    }

    console.log(pageStrings);

    return pageStrings;

}
```

Comment: When you say it should work, what does work mean. You should give an example of the current and expected output

Comment: Is it rewriting the pages variable or the pageStrings variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> var pageStrings = pages;
> ```

is creating a reference to the very same array object. When you access it via `pageString`, you alter the same object which `pages` does refer to. To [create a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript) of it (from which you then can splice, assign properties to, etc without altering `pages`), use

```
var pageStrings = pages.slice();
```

Comment: This is bizarre. I really thought variables were supposed to pass a value. Is this just an array thing or am I way off base?

Comment: The value here is the reference to the place in memory where the object is stored. Only primitive values like numbers, booleans or strings (which are immutable) do get copied every time.

Comment: Oh... That's where my confusion is coming from. Thanks a billion, Bergi!

Comment: It's an array/object thing. Bergi is spot on with his explanation. It will really stand out when your dealing with prototypal inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion is around the following line

```
var pageStrings = pages;
```

This does not create a copy of `pages` it simply creates a reference to `pages`.  This means any edit you make to the value of `pageStrings` (clearing, changing elements, etc ...) will show up on `pages` because they refer to the same variable.

If you want `pageStrings` to have a copy of the `pages` array then do the following

```
var pageStrings = pages.slice(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

`var pageStrings = pages;` is your hangup. Keep in mind that when you use `=` in this way, your new var will be a reference if the argument on the right is and array, object, or function. With strings and numbers you will get the copy you were expecting.